# create custom toolbar using fragment with popup menu

Tags: java, android, fragment, toolbar

I'm new to android and want to create custom toolbar for my first activity in android app including a popup menu. So searched a lot but couldn't find any thing useful.
here is my main activity code:

```
public class activity_test extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Toolbar toolbar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
       ActivityHolder.get_instance().set_last_activity(this);

       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.test_toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   }
}
```

this is layout for the activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/test_toolbar"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the fragment of toolbar is as below:

```
public class toolbar_fragment extends Fragment {

public toolbar_fragment(){
    super(R.layout.toolbar);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    }
    return true;
}
}
```

the following code is my main popup menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/downloads"
    android:title="downloads"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/bookmarks"
    android:title="bookmarks"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_us"
    android:title="about_us"/>

</menu>
```

finally I want to create a toolbar like this:

[image]

But the popup menu does not appear inside the toolbar.
Do you have any idea what should I do?